# Chrome Extension No manifest found in package

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Currently trying to add a new extension via the Chrome developer dashboard but getting the below error when I try to upload the zipped folder.

> No manifest found in package. Please make sure to put manifest.json at
> the root directory of the zip package.

This is what's inside the zipped folder, which as you can see, has the manifest in it's root.

[image]

The manifest is v3 and everything works fine unpacked in the extensions developer mode when I'm testing it.

Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was as simple as the name of the manifest being Manifest and not manifest... the capitalised M made all the difference...

there's a day of my life I'm not getting back.